# Image upload preview rotation (Safari on iOS)

Tags: javascript, image, web, safari, exif

I'm developing a fairly complex image uploading function for a website in ASP.Net/Javascript, with a WYSIWYG interface base around an image preview, all done client side before the user hits upload. But I've hit a fundamental snag: I don't really know what the user is seeing, before they even start transforming the image.

The Javascript for creating the preview client side is basically this jQuery bit

```
$('#inputPhotoUploader').change(function () {    
    var image = this.files[0];
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    imageClientURL = urlCreator.createObjectURL(image);

    var previewImage = document.createElement("img");
    previewImage.src = imageClientURL;

    $('#previewContainer').empty();
    $('#previewContainer').append(previewImage);
});
```

This creates an image in the #previewContainer div based on the file selected in the #inputPhotoUploader, without the user actually uploading anything. Great.

The problem is, that file often contains Exif data concerning rotation. The browser **might** automatically rotate the preview image based on this data (at least, on my iPhone it does). It might not, like on every desktop browser I've tested.

Eventually the user hits upload, and I get the original file, Exif data and all. But I have no idea how it was displayed to the user. Maybe their browser ignored the Exif data and displayed the image with the "incorrect" rotation, but the user wants it to look exactly that way and that's how my software should display it. Or maybe it was a quick shot with an iPhone, Safari auto-rotated it, and the user expects it to be displayed that way to everyone else because that's what the preview showed.

After the preview is created I do some other fancy image transformations but this basic problem still remains, what did the browser display? Right now the way I see it I need to either determine **if** the browser is automatically rotating the preview, or somehow make sure that **no** browser ever does. And I can only come up with ways to do the former, with ugly user agent stuff.

Is there a better way?

Comment: May I ask you to share your findings?

Comment: I've written many photo uploaders since and they all run into the same issue, when you give a browser a straight <img> tag with a src that has EXIF rotation, there's no way to know which orientation it will use without stupid user-agent hacks. Best solution I've found is to draw the image on a <canvas>, possibly applying the correct EXIF rotation manually first. Then you always KNOW what the user sees. Croppie (and other JS croppers) does this.